# How to fix bash or auto run /bin/bash on SSH login

Tags: ssh, bash

When logging in as `root` at my server everything works fine, but when I log in as `myusername` the bash is not working correctly.

The line starts with:

```
$
```

instead of

```
myusername@myserver:~$
```

and all specials keys like the arrow keys, tab keys, etc. won't work.

When I type `bin/bash` it works again, but I'd like to fix the problem or auto run `bin/bash` on login. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just need to change your shell. As that user, run:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Then sign out and back in.

After doing this the prompt doesn't look like you want, you'll need to start tweaking your environment's PS1 variable.

Comment: This is actually kind of dangerous since the question is asking about the `root` user. He's likely not using Linux. Root should stay with the default shell since the vendor is probably going to count on it being `ksh` or whatever else they chose. Instead, the real answer is "you shouldn't be logging in as root anyway".

Answer (score 16):

You need to change your shell. Run the command

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

then sign in again.

However, not all users have the right to change their own shell. If you use `sudo` remember to add your *username* to the `chsh` command as

```
sudo chsh <username> -s /bin/bash
```

otherwise you will change the shell for root inadvertently.

Comment: Fair point. Extended the answer slightly.

Comment: I was very naive to try: `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash` since my user didn't have permission to change shell. Your answer helped me solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One possible reason is that the default shell of *myusername* is not bash.

You can check the shell of your current user with:

- `echo ${SHELL}`
- `echo $0`

To change the user shell permanently see `man chsh`
, e.g.:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

If your sudo user password is disabled, you can edit the `/etc/passwd` directly, find the line where your user is and change the shell path into `/bin/bash`.

Here is the explanation of [/etc/passwd format](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add one more thing.

If sudo access is required to change the bash for that user, then you need to mention your username as well in the sudo command since without username it will apply to the root user.

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash <user>
```